# ROS2 galactic installation from source fail

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install ros2 Galactic ...

from binary I can't install many packages lik navigation2, nav2_bringup ... I got the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-galactic-nav2-bringup
```

and if I try to install it from source, i got build errors:

```
Starting >>> ament_cmake_nose                                                                                                                                                                 
--- stderr: cyclonedds
../../../bin/idlc: symbol lookup error: ../../../bin/idlc: undefined symbol: idl_printa_size__
make[2]: *** [src/tools/ddsperf/CMakeFiles/ddsperf_types_generate.dir/build.make:63: src/tools/ddsperf/ddsperf_types.c] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:599: src/tools/ddsperf/CMakeFiles/ddsperf_types_generate.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< cyclonedds [1min 45s, exited with code 2]
Finished <<< qt_gui_app [9.54s]
Aborted  <<< ament_cmake_nose [0.07s]
Aborted  <<< rttest [16.0s]                                                                                                                                                                       
Aborted  <<< rcutils [1min 54s]                                                                                                                                        
Aborted  <<< test_osrf_testing_tools_cpp [14.8s]                                                                                                                                  
Aborted  <<< fastrtps [8min 30s]                                                                                                  
Aborted  <<< rviz_ogre_vendor [11min 53s]                                              

Summary: 109 packages finished [13min 0s]
  1 package failed: cyclonedds
  6 packages aborted: ament_cmake_nose fastrtps rcutils rttest rviz_ogre_vendor test_osrf_testing_tools_cpp
  5 packages had stderr output: cyclonedds google_benchmark_vendor iceoryx_posh mimick_vendor rti_connext_dds_cmake_module
  214 packages not processed
```

******what is the best way to install ROS2 ? thanks for help******

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379454/ros2-galactic-installation-from-source-fail/) by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nav2 isn't yet available in the main repositories for Galactic. See the red squares in the right-most column of [status_page/ros_galactic_default.html?q=nav2](http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_galactic_default.html?q=nav2).

You'll have to wait for a "sync" (announced on ROS Discourse), or configure the testing repository.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2021-06-03**:
yeah thanks a lot